# How to view multiple capture image horizontally in react native?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs

I just want to capture image using camera API
Then Store it in array 
then view one by one image horizontally in React native

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Platform,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
      TouchableOpacity,
      Image,
      PixelRatio

    } from 'react-native';

    import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
    let ret;

    export default class Location extends Component {
        constructor(props){
         super(props);
        this.state = {
          latitude: null,
          longitude: null,
          address: 'address',
          MyAddress: null,
          error: null,
        }; 

      }

      state = {
        avatarSource: null,
        videoSource: null
      };


    selectPhotoTapped() {
    const options = {
      quality: 1.0,
      maxWidth: 500,
      maxHeight: 500,
      storageOptions: {
        skipBackup: true
      }
    };
```

To get Image, I used this.

```
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled photo picker');
      }
      else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      }
      else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      }
      else {
        let source = { uri: response.uri };
        // You can also display the image using data:
        //let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };
        this.setState({
          avatarSource: source
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Then how to process to view list of image like adpater.

```
        return (
            <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
```

To show the image in one view ,i have done this. i want to view multiple image like view pager.Like [] [] [] []

```
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.selectPhotoTapped.bind(this)}>
              <View style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer, {marginBottom: 20}]}>
              { this.state.avatarSource === null ? <Text>Select a Photo</Text> :
                <Image style={styles.avatar} source={this.state.avatarSource} />
              }
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
      }
    }
```

After few hours i have done this
First save image uri in array then show in list..

```
let dataStorage = [{uri: response.uri}, ...this.state.dataStorage]
        this.setState({dataStorage})



<FlatList
          horizontal
          data={this.state.dataStorage}
          renderItem={({ item: rowData }) => {
            return (
              <View style={[styles.avatar, styles.avatarContainer, {marginBottom: 20}]}>
                  {  <Image style={styles.avatar} source={{uri:rowData.uri}} /> }
              </View>

             );
              }
          }
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
        />
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, basically I am starting to react native as a beginner.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you want to learn how to write a code you will have more success using google. If you have problems with the code you have already written come back to SO and ask away.

Comment: did u get any idea to show multiple images in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Expo's ImagePicker this can be achieved.

Below is my code that might help you.

**Note: Its performance is slow but it works.**

1) state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: []
    };
  }
```

2) openCamera function:

```
openCamera = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.CAMERA,
      Permissions.CAMERA_ROLL
    );
    this.setState({
      hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted',
      hasGalleryPermission: status === 'granted'
    });

    if (this.state.hasCameraPermission && this.state.hasGalleryPermission) {
      ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
        aspect: [1, 1],
        quality: 0.2,
        base64: true
      })
        .then(async result => {
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            await this.setState({
              images: this.state.images.concat(result.uri)
            });
            Alert.alert(
              'Add another picture? ',
              null,
              [
                {
                  text: 'Yes',
                  onPress: () => this.openCamera()
                },
                { text: 'No' }
              ],
              { cancelable: false }
            );
          }
          console.log(this.state.images);
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }
  };
```

3) To display Image:

```
showImages = () => {
    let temp_image = [];
    this.state.images.map((item, index) => {
      let tempKey = item + '123';
      temp_image.push(
        <View key={tempKey}>
          <View
            key={index}
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              borderColor: '#dddddd'
            }}
          >
            <Image
              key={index}
              source={{ uri: item }}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                backgroundColor: 'silver',
                padding: 5,
                borderRadius: 5,
                height: null,
                width: null,
                margin: 3,
                resizeMode: 'cover'
              }}
            />
          </View>
          <View key={index + 1}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              key={index + 2}
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignSelf: 'center',
                width: '100%'
              }}
              onPress={() => {
                this.removeImage(index);
                this.forceUpdate();
              }}
            >
              <Text
                key={index + 3}
                style={{
                  alignSelf: 'center',
                  color: '#CE3C3E',
                  fontWeight: 'bold'
                }}
              >
                Delete
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
    console.log('state images: ', this.state.images);

    return temp_image;
  };
```

4) To delete image:

```
removeImage = index => {
    Alert.alert('Delete this image?', null, [
      {
        text: 'Yes',
        onPress: () => {
          this.state.images.splice(index, 1);
          // console.log(this.state.images);
          this.forceUpdate();
        }
      },
      { text: 'No' }
    ]);
  };
```

5) And in render() function:

```
<ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }} >
{this.showImages()}
</ScrollView>
```